# Upgrading MVC project in VS 2010 b2: The project type is not supported by this installation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

Consider the scenario of upgrading an ASP.NET MVC project.

This question is around up-converting a .sln with a .csproj that is of type ASP.NET MVC 1.0.

The conversion log shows this
The Visual Studio conversion wizard log gives this exception:

> The project file
>   'C:\MvcForums\MvcForums.csproj'
>   cannot be opened. The project type is
>   not supported by this installation.

After the conversion, the .sln contains this entry for the MVC app. The zerod-guid is obviously the root of the problem:

> Project("{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}") = "MvcForums", "MvcForums\MvcForums.csproj", "{5CDD5F8B-9192-4A63-B4B0-55244C835352}"

Question: How can we convert an MVC app using Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2? **Do you have to install MVC 1.0?**

Environment:

- Win 7
- No ASP.NET 1.0 installed
- Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 only
- [Stephen Walther's Forums sample app](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/09/05/asp-net-mvc-application-building-forums-2-create-the-first-unit-test.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here is a a tool](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2009/10/19/migrating-asp-net-mvc-1-0-applications-to-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx) that [Phil Haack](http://www.haacked.com) linked to upgrade mvc1 apps to mvc2 and be usable in 2010.  I would take a look at Phils blog, he links to the lead dev of mvc who has some info on the subject.